# Interact with a website built with Knockout.js in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, knockout.js

My goal is to **interact** with a website (not mine), getting and posting data from it to my Android app coded using Kotlin. The interaction part is to be done in the background, as the result is to be shown in a RecyclerView in my app.

The website in question uses **Knockout.js** - the responsiveness and dynamically changing data makes it impossible to use libraries such as Jsoup for my goal at hand.

I am an aspiring App developer (n00b), and **the question I have** for the more senior devs here: 
Is my project impossible? I have read it is "complex" to interact with a website that is dynamic, and I have also heard it is impossible. Is it? If not, could you **guide me to the libraries I should be using**? It is ok if these are in Java, I could probably look at adapting these to Kotlin.

Comment: If the website is providing REST API, then you can use Retrofit. Many tutorials are available online.

Comment: Hello Gushan! Alas it does not, no API is provided by the website in question.

Answer (score 1):

If the site you need to extract data from produces a predictable result when you make a request to a URL then it would be easy to extract the data you need from it using a library like Jsoup which you've mentioned. Looking at the Jsoup docs that would be something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
log(doc.title());
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
  log("%s\n\t%s", 
    headline.attr("title"), headline.absUrl("href"));
}
```

Where `doc.select` references an id in a given div (or other element) whose contents you're looking to extract.

Whether the site uses knockout or other JS library to help it render content shouldn't matter at all since all you're doing is parsing the string contents of the request--basically what you see when you view source in your browser. Knockout or any other script will have already run, doing its work in the rendering of the final HTML which you're going to parse with Jsoup.

But doing all of this is rather irregular as @Gushan indicates since normally unless you're doing some sort of scraping type of activity which would be weird for an android app, a site that wants to give you data and which you want to get data from will provide an API (usually some sort of REST API) that will simplify (document) how to go about getting that data. But I guess things aren't always like that. :)

Comment: Hi Steve! 
I had tried Jsoup, the with it is that it only catches the HTML prior to the dynamic JS gets started. 
The website in question is a notoriously bad build municipality booking website (for driving licenses). I had major issues with it myself when I needed it and wanted to help people out with a free booking app - as practice for myself getting started with coding and as a service to people. 
Even if the municipality wanted to change the website, due to legislature etc it would cost them a lot of money and take time. Long story short :)

Comment: I like the motivation. What you need is for your client to be "javascript aware" and it sounds like perform the interactions in JS to get the data you want to load. This could be pretty tricky to pull off in practice. Libraries like puppeteer (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) exist to help you automate this kind of thing for automated UI tests. But getting *that* to run in the context of your android app isn't going to work well. What you're really talking about is more in the realm of "web scraping". Googling that and Kotlin shows this: https://github.com/skrapeit/skrape.it.